# Подчеркивание последней строчки

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Добрый день,

Есть заголовки,которые обычно в 2 строчки, у данных заголовков нужно подчеркнуть именно нижнею строчку.

```
<h3><a>Строка в две строчки</a></h3>
```

Допустим в данном варианте, "две строчки" переносится и эти слова надо подчеркнуть.

Естественно вариант, брать нижнею строчку в доп тег, не подходит, т.к это все выводится автоматически через двиг и верстка адаптивная.

```
<h3><a>Строка в <span>две строчки</span></a></h3>
```

Пока в голову пришел только такой "костыль", подчеркивать через бордер тег a, делать нужный line-height, и с помощью :before, закрывать первое подчеркивание.
Данный вариант работает, но проблема именно в line-height и большом отступе между строчками, чтобы закрыть первый бордер.
p.s строка выравнивается по центру!
Надеюсь не сильно намудрил;)

Comment: а так? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qduceybp/

Comment: О как, неплохое решение) Но забыл добавить, что выравнивание идет по центру т.е так https://jsfiddle.net/qduceybp/2/

Comment: вот еще такой вариант https://jsfiddle.net/x82cc6qf/ - проверял только в Chrome

Comment: Вариант хороший и поддерживается браузерами более менее (first-line), но однако выделение идет через бордер (нужен именно dashed), либо через background и картинка бордера dashed. В вашем варианте, к сожалению можно использовать только text-decoration

Comment: "Пока в голову пришел только такой "костыль", подчеркивать через бордер тег a, делать нужный line-height, и с помощью :before, закрывать первое подчеркивание. Данный вариант работает, но проблема именно в line-height и большом отступе между строчками, чтобы закрыть первый бордер. "

А если line-height не трогать, то расстояние между строками нормальное

https://jsfiddle.net/b967g3tf/1/

Comment: Примерно так и сделано) Отличие только в line-height, т.к шрифт не стандартный и там перенос большой довольно)

Comment: Но хочется, сделать без костыля, т.к возможно будет и не в 2 строчки, а данный костыль закрывает первую строку

Comment: Тогда очень хочется узнать решение этой проблемы :-) Как придумаете - напишите ответ.

Comment: Да вот мне уже кажется, адекватно, без js, не получится сделать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/LL895spd/3/

```
h3
{
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
}

h3 a:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:-1px;
    background:#fff;
}

h3 a span{
    position:relative;
}

a
{       
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
    text-decoration: none;    
}
```

Ура!) Получилось сделать, без дубликатов и т.д) Как я раньше до такого решения не допер)
Спасибо всем!) 
ihhaman - спасибо тебе! Натолкнул меня на мысль данную)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю подчеркнуть непосредственно сам залоговок, а для ссылки убрать стандартное подчеркивание.

```
h3
{
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px blue;
}
a
{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/nk96jmd5/

Comment: если последнее слово не во всю длину строки, то подчеркивание будет выходит за пределы слова

Comment: Да и переносить с помощью br не вариант, т.к выводится через двиг и заранее не известно где переносить, если бы так можно было делать, то проще вторую строчку в <span></span>) и уже для него сделать стили)

Comment: br был для примера переноса приведен. С учетом дополнительных условий можно вывести два одинаковых тэга a и получить то, что нужно. Да, решение ужасное, но работает. https://jsfiddle.net/r9gro9vt/2/

Comment: У меня была такая идея, но данный вариант, очень ужасен) В h3,дублировать, думаю, поисковики не одобрят) По поводу первого варианта, согласен с lexxl, не всегда первая строка меньше второй

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nk96jmd5/1/, как то так получается к первому варианту. Думаю и ищу решение дальше) js очень не хочется использовать.

Comment: Более хороший вариант с одним тэгом, но дублированием текста ссылки в data-параметре: https://jsfiddle.net/LL895spd/1/

Comment: Думаю тоже самое, что и прошлый вариант( Получается, только дублируем 3 раза, допустим, даже тег data-text, нормальное явление, но по сути, добавляем, через before, тот же самый текст... Хотя честно говоря, не знаю, как поисковые относятся к такому